# Problems creating android build with Telerik Appbuilder; android-support-v4.jar" already exists

Tags: android, telerik, android-support-library, telerik-appbuilder

Im having trouble building my app through the build process of Telerik Appbuilder. We are using a modified version of the `multi imagepicker` plugin wich has a reference to the `android-support-v4.jar` in the `plugin.xml`, like so

```
<source-file src="src/android/Library/libs/android-support-v4.jar" target-dir="libs"/>
```

When I try to create a build via de Telerik AppBuilder option it gives the following error and doesnt complete the build.

```
android-support-v4.jar" already exists
```

When I remove the reference from the `plugin.xml` and try create a build again, it finishes the build without any errors but then the plugin does not work.

I've already tried to use the plugin in a `cordova` (5.4.1) test project and have build it via CLI commands. With cordova I can successfully build a test project **with** the plugin and the reference to the android support library in place. The test app deploys succesfully to my android device via `cordova run android` The plugin and its modifications are fully functional in the test project.

FYI => If I remove the android support library reference in the `plugin.xml` in the cordova test project the entire project does not build. I get loads of compiling errors.

Does anyone has had the same experience or has an indication of what causes the error when I build via the Telerik Appbuilder tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error for conflicting android-support-v4.jar is caused by having incompatible plugins in your project. In order to use the latest available android support v4 library you should remove the jar from your plugin and replace the `lib-file` element of your plugin.xml with `<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" />`.

Additionally, if you have other plugins which install their own version of the library, you'll have to either upgrade them to their latest version (which hopefully will have been fixed) or make the same modification in them. For more information on this issue you can refer to the following AppBuilder forum thread: http://www.telerik.com/forums/breaking-change-introduces-build-failure-for-android